# Connecting a non-galvanic isolated RS-485

Tags: rs485

I would like to consult if I am designing RS-485 connection correctly without risk of damaging anything.

Main goal: I want to get data (e.g. flow temp) from Danfoss ECL 210 district heating control via modbus RS-485 over wifi to homeassistant.

The challenge: ECL210 RS-485 has non galvanic isolation by which I understand that any incorrect action might destroy whole unit?

As I understand:

- I need to connect common ground and earth it at one place, e.g. mounting rack bolt (both devices will be close).
- Add 120 ohm resistor between A&B at both ends.
- Both devices will feed 220v AC (I live in EU) but as RS-485 serial server uses DC, thus will have either built in transformer or via separate one (if it is safer?)
- I should get RS-485 over wifi serial server with A/B/G ports as I assume devices without ground point is not an option? e.g. reasonably priced Protoss PW11-HE http://www.hi-flying.com/pe11

[image: wiring diagram]

Would that be a correct set-up?

I am cautious that seller cannot confirm if RS-485 device has isolated RS-485. If not, is it still ok or shall I get isolated one or i.e. add isolated converter in between and even separate circuit breaker if that is more secure..

Comment: How long is the run between units? What speeds?

Comment: Max 20cm/8in, <10mbit

Comment: Looking at the ECL 210 manual, it says it has non-isolated RS485, but it doesn't say from what it is not isolated.

If the unit is powered by an internal switching power supply which is isolated from mains, the RS485 output will also be isolated from mains even if it doesn't use any special isolation components. In this case, since the unit has no other non-isolated port, adding optocouplers to isolate the RS485 port would mean isolating it twice which is not necessary. On the other hand, if it is powered by a non-isolated power supply, then that would be a problem. Can you check?

Comment: Also if your HomeAssistant machine is nearby, I recommend this [USB-RS485 converter](https://www.waveshare.com/product/iot-communication/wired-comm-converter/usb-to-rs232-uart-fifo/usb-to-rs232-485-ttl.htm). It's convenient because it doesn't need a separate power supply thanks to USB. The same store also sells RS485/Modbus-Ethernet/WiFi translators, which I haven't tried.

Comment: The manual says about "galvanic isolation" that the design has less that 6mm gap between live and isolated parts so it should not be considered safe even if it should be isolated. But this question is about using a product so you might better ask the manufacturer what does non-galvanic means and how you can safely connect to it. We cannot know what it means unless we see schematics.

Answer (score 0):

Isolation just means that the device won't send DC through the wires and probably won't mean anything for your application. If two RS485 devices are on the same ground, isolation most likely won't make any difference at all. In addition RS485 is somewhat tolerant to having devices on different grounds as long as the differential of the grounds is like a few volts or less.

The only other case that you would need isolation is if you needed to protect against kV voltage in an industrial environment. The most important thing is to make sure the RS-485 signals are at the same voltage levels as some devices use a TTL transciever. The devices may already have a 120ohm resistor, you might be able to check this with the device off with a DMM.

Comment: The "non-galvanic" may mean it's not floating but earth/ground referenced. There are also some vague hints that there is just so small gap between mains and low voltage parts that it can't be considered galvanically isolated by standards, like DALI wiring, because DALI wiring runs in a 5-wire mains cable, 3 for L/N/PE and 2 for data. So this Danfoss device should have power supply isolated from N/L at least. If it did have a floating power supply which has no galvanic reference to earth/ground then you do need to connect to RS-485 bus with 3 wires, A,B and the ground reference for them.